# Obtaining the equation of circle in a 3-dimentional space.

Tags: circles, 3d

My thinking:

To obtain the equation of a circle in a three dimentional space we need to get the intersection of a sphere and a plane. According to me this can be done by :
$(equation\ of\ sphere)^2+(equation \ of \ plane)^2=0$

but to test this I don't have the adequate software.
So my question is:

Am I thinking in the right way?

If not, then where I am going wrong?

If yes, then can you help me with a sample of the graph of the equation.

Thank you :)

Comment: This question is directly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184038/269624 and

Comment: So how should I go about it? I am new to geometry so I am not aware of much techniques. It would be really nice if you could throw some light.

Comment: As far as I can see your method works just fine, but it depends on the context: what do you need this equation for? Is it an assignment or do you need it for some practical application

Comment: What do you mean "sample of the graph of the equation"? You most likely know how a circle looks like, so what are you really asking?

Comment: Nothing like that, it just came to my mind so just wanted to clarify it out.

Comment: Also, please look at the answers to the question I linked, they seem to answer your question as well

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks a lot. Whatever I have written is same as what the last bullet of the first answer (in that link) says.