# Parametric equations for intersection between plane and circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

So I was looking at this question [Determine Circle of Intersection of Plane and Sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383/determine-circle-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere)
but I need to know how to find a parametric equation for intersections such as these.  My particular question is to find a parametric equation for the intersection between the plane

$$x+y+z=1$$ and unit sphere centered at the origin.

I started out my question by substituting 
$$
z=-x-y+1$$ into 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1  $$ deriving 
$$x^2+y^2+(-x-y+1)^2=1$$
and getting $$2x^2+2y^2+2xy-2x-2y=0$$ but I am unsure how to proceed from here.
I also tried to use the vector equation of the plane 
$$r(u, v)=(0,0,1)+(2,1,-3)u+(1,1,-2)v$$ but I am not sure how that would help.

Comment: If you need that for integrating a function over a sphere section, I suggest you to exploit symmetry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plane $ \zeta = \{(x,y,z) : x + y + z = 1\},$ is perpendicular to the vector
$\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$.

Two points on $\zeta$ are 
$\mathbf O = \left( \dfrac 13,\ \dfrac 13,\ \dfrac 13 \right)
\text{ and }
\mathbf A = (0,0,1)$.

Since $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{OA}} = \dfrac 13 \langle -1, -1, 2 \rangle$,
 the unit vector
$\overrightarrow u = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt 6} \langle -1, -1, 2 \rangle$ 
is parallel to the plane $\zeta$.

Since $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{OA}} \times
 \langle 1,1,1 \rangle = \langle -1, 1, 0 \rangle$, then the unit vector 
$\overrightarrow v = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} \langle -1, 1, 0 \rangle$ is parallel to the plane $\zeta$ and 
$\overrightarrow u \perp \overrightarrow v$.

So we can parameterize the plane, $\zeta$ as
$$\zeta(s,t)
  = \mathbf O + s \overrightarrow u + t \overrightarrow v
  = \left(
         \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac{s}{\sqrt 6} - \dfrac{t}{\sqrt 2},
         \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac{s}{\sqrt 6} + \dfrac{t}{\sqrt 2},
         \dfrac 13 + \dfrac{2s}{\sqrt 6}
    \right)$$

As ugly as the following looks

$$\left( \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac{s}{\sqrt 6} - \dfrac{t}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 +
\left( \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac{s}{\sqrt 6} + \dfrac{t}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 +
\left( \dfrac 13 +  \dfrac{2s}{\sqrt 6}\right)^2 = 1 $$

It simplifies to $s^2 + t^2 = \dfrac  23$

So we let
$s = \sqrt{\dfrac 23}\cos \theta$ and 
$t = \sqrt{\dfrac 23}\sin \theta$ and simplify. We get

$$\zeta(s,t)
  = \left(
         \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac {\cos \theta}{3}  - \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt 3},\;
         \dfrac 13 -  \dfrac {\cos \theta}{3} + \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt 3},\;
         \dfrac 13 +  \dfrac {2\cos \theta}{3}
    \right)$$

a more intuitive answer

---

Let $S$ be the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

Let $P$ be the plane $x + y + z = 1$.

Let $C$ be the circle $C = S \cap P$.

The unit vector $U = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} \langle 1,1,1 \rangle$ is perpendicular to $P$.

The line $x = y = z$

- passes through, $(0,0,0)$,  the center of $S$
- passes through, $X$, the center of $C$
- is perpendicular to $P$

The distance from $P$ to the center of $S$ is
$ \dfrac{\left| 0 + 0 + 0 - 1 \right|}{\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}} 
   = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

The center of $C$ is at
    $X = (0,0,0) + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}U
= \left( \dfrac 13,\dfrac 13, \dfrac 13 \right)$.

The radius of $C$ is $r = \sqrt{1 - \dfrac 13} = \sqrt{\dfrac 23}$.

We need to find two points, $A$ and $B$, on $C$ such that
$\overrightarrow{XA} \perp \overrightarrow{XB}$.

- $A = (1,0,0)$ is a point on $C$.
- $\left \| \overrightarrow{XA} \right \|  =
     \left \| \left( \dfrac 23, -\dfrac 13, -\dfrac 13  \right) \right \| =
     \sqrt{\dfrac 23}$
- $U \times \sqrt{\dfrac 32} \; \overrightarrow{XA} = 
  \left( 0, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \right)$
  is a unit vector, in P, that is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{XA}$.
- $\overrightarrow{XB} = 
  \sqrt{\dfrac 23} \left( 0, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}  \right) =
  \left( 0, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}  \right)$

\begin{align}
C &=
  X 
  + \cos \theta \; \overrightarrow{XA}
  + \sin \theta \; \overrightarrow{XB}
\\
C &= \left( \dfrac 13,\dfrac 13, \dfrac 13 \right) 
  + \cos \theta \; \left( \dfrac 23, -\dfrac 13, -\dfrac 13  \right)
  + \sin \theta \; \left( 0, \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3}, -\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3}  \right) 
\\
C &= \dfrac 13(1 + 2 \cos \theta, \;
               1 - \cos \theta + \sqrt 3 \sin \theta, \;
               1 - \cos \theta - \sqrt 3 \sin \theta)
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, this is a great solution. Can you please suggest some books where I can study more about the justification of these equations and method? I would appreciate it, thanks. :)

Comment: @learningmaths: I'm old. Moise and Penrose were my favorite authors. I found out quickly that a good picture and the right notation can clear the landscape significantly.

Comment: Hi Steven. I found this book fom Moise: ELEMENTARY GEOMETRY from an Advanced Standpoint. Is this the one you are thining about? What about Penrose? he has so many. Any title you recommend for this topic. Thanks. Kind regards

Comment: I really liked Moise's geometry and calculus books, Searle's book LINEAR MODELS, and any if Penrose's differential equations book (though none of them are elementary).

Comment: Thans for that. kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

Steven Gregory gives an excellently crafted solution.

One can also approach the problem from the standpoint of a particle moving at a constant velocity in a circle through the points $(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0),\,(0,0,1)$ centered at $\left(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}\right)$. The radius of this circle is $\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}$.

This suggests using a sinusoidal for each coordinate with phase shifts adjusted "equally around the circle" so to speak. Something like

\begin{equation}
  x(t)=\tfrac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\cos(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
     y(t)=\tfrac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\cos\left(t+\tfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  z(t)=\tfrac{1}{3}+\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\cos\left(t-\tfrac{2\pi}{3}\right)
\end{equation}

A check confirms that

\begin{equation}
x(t)+y(t)+z(t)=1
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
x^2(t)+y^2(t)+z^2(t)=1
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your equation by 2:

$$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y = 0$$
Let us toss the left hand side coefficients into a matrix:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}0&-1&1\\-1&1&0\\1&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

Now you can notice a symmetry. If treated as a matrix, it is symmetric. This makes reasonable the substitution $$\cases{x=s-t\\ y=s+t}$$
if we do it, we get (for the left hand side):

$$(s-t)^2+(s+t)^2+(s-t)(s+t) - (s+t)-(s-t)=\\
  \underset{square 1}{\underbrace {s^2-2st+t^2}} +\underset{square 2}{\underbrace {s^2+2st+t^2}} + \underset{conjugate}{\underbrace {s^2-t^2}}-2s=\\
3s^2+t^2-2s$$

Now this should be easier to work with and/or interpret.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's name some points. Let $O=(0,0,0)$, $X=(1,0,0)$, $Y=(0,1,0)$, and $Z=(0,0,1)$. Let $A$ be the center of the circle we are trying to find. Let $K$ be the midpoint of $XY$. Note that $K=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0\right)$.

Let's consider right triangle $ZOK$:

[image: Bad 2D Diagram]

We note that A is the base of the altitude to the hypotenuse. Since $OZ=1$ and $OK=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, $OA=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. Because $A$ must be of the form $(n,n,n)$, we conclude that $A=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)$. We can also calculate that $AZ=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$. Note that $AZ$ is the radius of the circle.

[image: Bad 3D diagram]

Now, let's invent a new 2D coordinate system with new unit vectors. $A$ will be the center of this coordinate system. Rotate $AZ$ 90 degrees clockwise on the plane $x+y+z=1$. This new vector (orange) will be one of our unit vectors, which we will call $u$. The other will be $AZ$ itself (pink), which we will call $v$. Imagine extending vector $u$ into a line and moving it down to the $xy$-plane. It makes a 45-45-90 triangle with the $x$ and $y$ axes. Since $u$ has no $z$-component, we conclude that $u=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0\right)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},0\right)$.

[image: Another bad 2D diagram]

Drop a perpendicular from point A to the $z$ axis. Call the foot of this perpendicular $H$. Note that triangle $ZOA$ is similar to $ZOK$. Using this fact, we can calculate that $ZH=\frac{2}{3}$. Note that $ZH$ is the $z$-component of $v$. We can also calculate that $AH=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$. Imagine moving $AH$ down to the $xy$-plane. We see that $AH$ forms 45 degrees with the $x$ and $y$ axes. We conclude that $v=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$.

The equation of the circle is $$A+u\cos(t)+v\sin(t)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cos(t)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},0\right)+\sin(t)\left(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Adding everything together, we get a final answer:

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos(t)-\sin(t),1+\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos(t)-\sin(t),1+2\sin(t)\right)$$