# Finding the equation of a circle of sphere

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

How do i describe the circle resulting from the intersection of the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ and the sphere centred at $O(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)$ with radius $R$

I found that the plane-sphere distance  $\rho$  is less than the radius of the sphere so a circle is formed
I also found from my diagram that the radius $r$ of my circle follows $r = \sqrt{R^2-{\rho}^2}$
But how do I go about finding the coordinates of the centre

Let $\vec{n}$ be normal to the plane, $O'$ the centre of the circle
I thought of saying 
$\vec{n} \times \vec{OO'} = \vec{0}$
Since $\vec{OO'}$ is parallel to $\vec{n}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Determine Circle of Intersection of Plane and Sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383).

Answer (score 1):

The centre of your circle is the intersection of the plane with the line that passes through the centre of the sphere and is perpendicular to the plane.

[image]

Comment: If I got you right I should write the parametric equation of the line that passes through the centre of the sphere and is parallel to the normal of the plane , substitute x,y,z in the plane and solve for the parameter?

Comment: @arsenestein I added a picture