# Find radius and centre of circle given three points

Tags: vectors

The question is to find the centre and radius in the circle that is where the plane going through A, B and C cuts the sphere.

The sphere has the equation
$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2=4$

The three points
$A(2,2,1+\sqrt{2})$, $B(0,1+\sqrt{2},2)$ and $C(1,1,3)$

Say the centre is $S(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

$abs(\vec {AS})$ $=$ $abs(\vec {BS})$ $=$ $abs(\vec {CS})=R$ where $R$ is the radius.

I have three equations, and the three unknown coordinates of S, but that set of equation is impossible to solve by hand, how would I otherwise solve it?

Comment: a related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383/determine-circle-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere

Comment: Isn't there  a typo in the coordinates of A,B,C ?

Comment: First you have to find the equation of the plane passing through three points, the rest is given in the reference in comment.

Comment: Bob, your approach is not wrong. But: the points=solutions of the system you have create a line. It is the line orthogonal to the plane $(ABC).$ Therefore you need something more (an equation of the plane or to minimize R or ...)

Comment: @user376343 there is not a typo, but thanks i now solved it. If i also added the equation that the coordinates for W are in the plane of A, B and C i could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the radius of the circle is an operation which is invariant by translation.

Let us operate a translation bringing the center of the sphere at the origin, using vector

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The images of points $A,B,C,\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is the center of the sphere) become:

$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\s\end{pmatrix}, \ \ B'=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\s\\1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ C'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}, \ \ O=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Where:

$$s:=\sqrt{2}$$

We check that points $A',B',C'$ belong to the sphere with center $O$ and radius $2$.

The equation of plane $P:=A'B'C'$ is easily found to be:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&x\\
   1&s&0&y\\
   s&1&2&z\\
   1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

giving:

$$(3-2s)x+(s-3)y+(-1-s)z+(2+2s)=0\tag{1}$$

The (shortest) distance from origin $O$ to plane $P$ is therefore:

$$d=\dfrac{2+2s}{\sqrt{(3-2s)^2+(s-3)^2+(-1-s)^2}}=\dfrac{2+2s}{\sqrt{31-16s}}$$

> $$d\approx 1.6687$$

But $d=OD$ where $D$ is the center of the circumscribed circle to $A'B'C'$. Therefore, using Pythagoras in triangle $ODA'$ (see the figure in the referenced document given by @Robin to Roxel):

$$OD^2+DA'^2=OA'^2 \ \iff  \ \ \text{radius} = DA'=\sqrt{OA'^2-OD^2}\approx \sqrt{4-1.6687^2}=1.1025$$

---

In order to find the coordinates of $D$, just express the fact that :

$$\vec{OD}=k\begin{pmatrix}(3-2s)\\(s-3)\\(-1-s)\end{pmatrix}$$

for a certain constant $k$ where we have taken the normal vector to plane $A'B'C'$ (see equation (1)).

Knowing that $\vec{OD}^2=d^2$, one obtains readily the value of $k$. In this way, (2) gives us the coordinates of $D$, Now it remains to add to these coordinates the opposite of the coordinates of translation vector $T$ to obtain the coordinates of the center of original triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Any reaction ?...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i dont understand the math, that is too advanced for the level this should be solved at (last year of high school)

Comment: Say me what you do not understand... Do you find the same radius as me $1.1025$ by a different method ?

Comment: I have never seen a 4x4 determinant, i solved it using the fact that the absolute value of all three vectors from the centre to the three different points and using that the coordinates of the centre are in the plane going through A B and C.

Comment: Forget the determinant. The important fact is that you find the same equation for the plane (by other means). Finally, do you find the same radius 1.1025 as me ?

Comment: Yes, i found the same radius