# How to find the intersection of a rotated plane and a sphere.

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

Suppose I have a plane described in the following form which is rotated t degrees.

$x = u * cos(t)$

$y = v$

$z = -u * sin(t)$

And a sphere such as

$x = sin(v')cos(u')$

$y = sin(v')sin(u')$

$z = cos(v')$

For instance, consider the following diagram

[image]

I want to get the equation describing the ellipse which is the intersection of the sphere and the plane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you may use some ideas from the answer to [Determine Circle of Intersection of Plane and Sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383/determine-circle-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).