How to explicitely reduce the expression of the intersection of plan and sphere from 3D to 2D?
If you have for example a plan ($\mathcal{P}$) and a sphere ($\mathcal{S}$), let say :
$$(\mathcal{P}) \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace z= \frac{1}{2} $$
$$(\mathcal{S}) \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 $$
When you want to get the intersection, injecting ($\mathcal{P}$) in the expression of ($\mathcal{S}$), you get :
$$(\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{S})  \enspace \enspace \enspace \enspace x^2 + y^2 =\frac{3}{4}  $$
The equation $(\mathcal{P} \cap \mathcal{S}) $ is supposed to be the equation a circle, but because we are still in 3D, this equation gives an infinite cylinder in space, having now a free parameter $z$, able to take any value.
In other words, how to only represent the circle in 3D space.
Thus, how to get a general expression of this 2D intersection, taking in consideration that we are still in 3D ?
Thank you in advance for your perspective.

Keep the other equation $z=\frac12.$ Just as two planes are needed to define the intersection line, you need two equations to get the circle from the cylinder and plane.

Not marking as a duplicate, but does this answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943383/determine-circle-of-intersection-of-plane-and-sphere/1218805#1218805
